# statistical analysis of events in a given time interval

Tags: time-series, probability, biostatistics

I am attempting to analyze biological data, to see whether the number of events in a given time interval is more/less than expected based on the overall frequency. How would one approach this?

An example of how I would frame this:
Out of 100 ms, 16/44 events occur in 15 ms, and 28/44 events occur in the remaining 85 ms.
Do more events occur in the 15 ms interval than expected based on the overall frequency? 
And I guess the null hypothesis is that there is a random distribution of the 44 events over the 100 ms.

Comment: How was that interval of 15 ms found?  Was it designated before you looked at the data--that is, completely independent of the data and how the experiment was run--or is it perhaps an interval centered around a time of greatest event intensity?

Comment: It's a very rough estimate of when you would expect to see polysynaptic events (ie. stimulus-evoked events) - up to 15 ms after the stimulus. After 15 ms, you wouldn't expect the activity to be evoked, and therefore they are spontaneous events. Does that make any sense? There will definitely be spontaneous events, the question is whether there are stim-evoked events- and the only way to tell is whether frequency of events in the first 15 ms rises above what one would expect from the spontaneous frequency.

Comment: You could condition on the total number of events and do a one-sample proportions test (or equivalently a chi-squared goodness of fit test); treating the count in the first interval as a binomial. The main advantage of the proportions test rather than the chi-squared is the ability to accommodate a one-tailed alternative.

Comment: @Glen_b, thank you for your response! My apologies, however, I've only taken one very intro college level stats class, so I'm still working at understanding how to apply different tests- I will try to look  up what these things mean, but any further elaboration would be greatly appreciated. :) Again, thanks!

Comment: For example, could I say that, in 15% of the time, there were 16 out a total of 44 events- and use something like this http://stattrek.com/online-calculator/binomial.aspx ? (With p = .15, number of trials= 44, successes = 16?) - and then say that probability of getting >= 16 events is 0.0004, so you can say with p<.05 that this is significantly more than expected number of events within that time interval? Is that the same (similar) to what you are saying? Also, when applied to other cases, is this predicated on underlying assumptions/total number of "successes" or "events"?

Comment: You're kind of on the right track, but some things need to be cleared up. I'll expand my comments into something of an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> to see whether the number of events in a given time interval is more/less than expected based on the overall frequency.
>
> An example: Out of 100 ms, 16/44 events occur in 15 ms, and 28/44 events occur in the remaining 85 ms. Do more events occur in the 15 ms interval than expected based on the overall frequency? And I guess the null hypothesis is that there is a random distribution of the 44 events over the 100 ms.

If events are uniformly distributed over the total 100 ms interval, then the expected number of evens in the first 15 ms is the total number of events $\times$ 15/100.

I interpret your question as implying a *one tailed* alternative, but you should take care about how well justified that is and consider whether the two tailed alternative is what you need.

I will further assume events are independent (this assumption may not be justified, you should consider carefully whether it is reasonable).

Let $X$ be the number of events in the first 15 ms.

Given the assumptions, and conditioning on the total number of events observed, the number of events, $X$ in 15 ms will be binomial with $n=44$ and $p=0.15$.

$H_0: \text{Events occur at the same rate before and after 15ms}$
$H_1: \text{Events occur at a higher rate in the first 15ms}$

Or in symbols:

$H_0: p=0.15$
$H_1: p>0.15$

We observe $x=16$. The probability of observing 16 or more events in the first 15 ms is 0.0004022:

[image]

At typical significance levels you'd reject $H_0$ and conclude there was a higher rate of events in the first 15ms.

Comment: If I repeat this analysis x number of times on independent samples, can I use the Holm Sidak correction for multiple comparisons the same way you would for a t test?

Comment: Are you trying to come to some overall conclusion about the first 15 ms having a higher rate, or is this for a collection of separate conclusions about the initial period (say under different conditions where some might and some might not have higher rates)?

Comment: In this case, the same manipulation was done to 12 cells, separately, and the question is which/how many cells showed a statistically significant increase in activity during a particular time window.

Comment: That sounds a little closer toward the estimation side than the testing side, but yes, if you do multiple tests and you want some overall control of type I error rate you could do some correction for multiple comparisons, including as far as I can tell, Holm-Sidak.

Comment: What do you mean by closer to the estimation side vs testing side? Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you know the times of the events to a precision about 100 times that of the average interval or greater, it is possible to use event interval analysis to examine changes in rate. In such an analysis, the intervals between events are used as the primary data, and a uniform distribution of events is the typical null hypothesis. While this has previously been used for event sequences of much lower frequency, the method should be applicable. See Lemon, J. (2014) The analysis of event rates using intervals. The Quantitative Methods for Psychology, 10(1): 68-76.